# Which method of HTTPS redirecting using .htaccess is best?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, https

I, like many, am currently using this method of redirecting all traffic from port 80 to https:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Though I have also used the following method with success:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

and have seen this method work, though am not using it anywhere currently:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

With 3 good options (and potentially several more), along with Chrome and others now [showing security warnings](https://searchengineland.com/google-emails-warnings-webmasters-chrome-will-mark-http-pages-forms-not-secure-280907) for non https versions, I'm wondering what the best way forward should be. Is one of these methods explicitly better than another, or is it going to be very case-specific? Will a 'best-practice' emerge? With https as the new standard, is there any reason to use `R` instead of `R=301`, given the https redirect should almost always be permanent?

I ask because like many freelancers I am far from being an expert in server configuration, but it still plays a major role in the successful launch of even the smallest website these days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can specify the domain name, the best solution is to combine both https and www:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [OR,NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteRule ^ https://www.exemple.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
```

But in no case you should first redirect to https without www, or to http with or without www.

And you need to redirect 301 (with [R=301]) and not 302 (by default with [R]).